# Where does the Table Type gets stored in sql server? And how can we alter it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was reading about Table Value Parameter which seems interesting.. but i want to know that when we define a table type in database where does it get saved? What is its scope? And How can i modify that type .. suppose i created a table type as...

```
CREATE TYPE DeptType AS TABLE
(
DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Now how can i get the schema of DeptType in future? In case of stored procedure its as simple as `sp_helptext [ProcedureName]`. How can i modify it? What is the scope of this type?

Comment: How about `sys.objects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.table_types tt ON c.[object_id] = tt.type_table_object_id 
WHERE tt.name = 'DeptType'

SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.[type] = 'TT'
    AND o.name LIKE 'TT_DeptType%'
```

How to modify -

```
Database Explorer -> 
  <your db> -> 
    Programmability -> 
      Types -> 
        User-Defined Table Types -> DROP-CREATE script
```

Comment: I can now see the columns of table type but how can i modify it if i want to? Is there a way to get the create script of this table type? So that i can make changes to it and alter or recreate the type?

Comment: @devart sorry i know this is a new question ... can we really see table parameter in sys.objects ??

Comment: That was very helpful @Devart ... as i can see i am unable to alter the script so i guess only way to alter is to copy the create script change it .. drop the existing type and recreate the type with modified script.. right? Also , is there a way to get this script though query? Instead of using the Explorer?

Comment: Yes, but you need keep in mind the dependencies between your table type and another `DDL` objects.

Answer (score 2):

> What is its scope?

It belongs to a schema, the same as a table, view, stored procedure, etc, would. For usage, it can only be used within the same database as it resides. There's no way to reference a table type from another database (even within the same instance), and two table types declared identically in separate databases are not interchangable.

> And How can i modify that type

You cannot, unfortunately. The pattern to SQL commands is that if `CREATE` is used to bring an object into existence, `ALTER` is used to modify that object (And `DROP` to remove it). By looking at the [`ALTER` statements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879314.aspx), you'll note that there is no `ALTER TYPE`.

The best you can do is `DROP` the type and `CREATE` it again with its altered form. Unfortunately, to do so you have to drop all dependent objects first, then drop the type, then create it, then recreate all dependent objects.